# Regex to match multiple possible options

Tags: javascript, regex

I am unable to give a proper title for this issue I am having, but I am trying to figure out how to write a regex that will be able to match a couple of possible options from the list below.

> Describe what rules should regex consider as valid?

- Must start with `dfr`
- Must contain one dash `-` after keyword that it begins with
- Can contain double dash `--` if it continues with one of those keywords `base`, `root`, `x`, `y`
- If contains double dash + keyword e.g. `dfr--base` must contain another dash after it e.g. `dfr--base-`
- Afterwards it can contain only letters, it should validate lowercase and camelCase only.
- Should be chained with single dash `-` and contain letters afterwards

> To clarify with some examples, those should be valid:

```
dfr--base-color-dark
dfr--root-size
dfr--x-spacing
dfr-spacing
dfr-fontWeight
dfr-borderRadius-extraSmall
dfr-grid-columns
```

> I think that I'm very bad with regex, but of course I spent some time trying to figure this out... Playing around with [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com)

```
^dfr-((-?(base|root|x|y)+([a-zA-Z-])+)$|([a-zA-Z-]+)$)
```

It seems to be working, but I am not sure if this is good enough, does it have some failure cases, etc...

I attempted to give it a shot at a few examples that should not be valid, but it seems to be bad...

```
dfra // good
dfra- // good
dfr-Q // good
qwe-asd // good
dfr--asd // good
dfr-as2dqw // good
dfr--base--dog // good
dfr--root--x // fails (it should not pass with double dash of two keywords)
dfr-x1223 // good
```

Any help is appreciated. I am struggling so hard over here  !

**UPDATE #1:**

I have just updated my regex a little bit and it seems to be better, not quite sure yet.

**UPDATE #2:**

Here are some examples of what it should be able to validate and what it should not be able to validate:

```
// Should pass
dfr-borderRadius-extraSmall
dfr-borderRadius-full
dfr--base-color-dark
dfr--root-fontSize-small
dfr--base-fontSize
dfr-borderWidth

// Should fail
not-dfr
not-dfr-asd
dfr-1
dfr-@
dfr--a
dfr--base
dfr-root-
dfr--x-1
dfr--root--x
dfr--root-Something
dfr-border--x
dfr-asd-Asd
```

Comment: is the double dash before `base`, `root`, `x`, `y` mandatory or it is possible to have a single dash too?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - If one of the keywords is used, double dash is mandatory.

Comment: Are keywords allowed after the first group of letters?

Comment: You may try: [`/^dfr-(?:-(?:base|root|x|y)-)?[a-z][a-zA-Z]*(?:-[a-z][a-zA-Z]*)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/5eIRHe/2/)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Nope. It is either `dfr--keyword-somethingHere` or `dfr-somethingHere`. No keywords allowed after `somethingHere`, just right after `dfr`

Comment: Ok, I suggest: [`^dfr(?:--(?:base|root|[xy]))?(?:-(?!(?:base|root|[xy])(?:-|$))[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/EaAIxi/1/)

Comment: @anubhava - I will kindly ask you to post an answer and explain the regex if possible. It does work...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - I will also kindly ask you to post an answer and explain the regex if possible. It also works...

Comment: Casimire's regex is more complete so you should accept his answer. I have upvoted your question and his answer ++

Comment: @anubhava - Alright. Thank you for your feedback and comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
^dfr(?:--(?:base|root|[xy]))?(?:-(?!base\b|root\b|[xy]\b)[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*)+$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBbnuX/1)

details:

```
^dfr
(?:--(?:base|root|[xy]))? # optional keyword

(?: # group for other parts
    -
    (?!base\b|root\b|[xy]\b) # negative lookahead (not followed by a keyword)
    [a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)* # a camelCase word
)+ # repeat one or more times
$
```

Note that a word-boundary suffices to check if a word is followed by a dash or the end of the string, since only letters and dashes are allowed in the string.

Comment: Still finding it a little hard to wrap my mind around this. Seems like I wasn't quite close, but maybe after a couple more hours I'd get near it...

Never heard of non-capturing group and never used negative lookahead in my life. It's also very interesting use of word boundary.

I appreciate your complete answer!